# sqlerror help please

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-insert

```
insert into dbo.leerlingen 
('1', 
'Reduan de Boer', 
'postweg12', 
'4589 vb', 
'zelhem', 
'23841')
```

when i type this in i get this error can anyone help me please

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Proper syntax of an insert statement is `Insert [into] TableName (<columns list>) VALUES (<values list>)`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `values` keyword to introduce the list of values to insert:

```
insert into dbo.leerlingen values('1', 'Reduan de Boer', 'postweg12', '4589 vb', 'zelhem', '23841')
                         --^--> here
```

Note that it is a good practice to enumerate the columns that you want to insert into: this makes the query easier to read to someone who does not know your table structures. Also, if new columns are added that are nullable, you don't need to modify the query.

```
insert into dbo.leerlingen(id, name, ...)  --> enumerate all target columns here
values('1', 'Reduan de Boer', 'postweg12', '4589 vb', 'zelhem', '23841')
```

Finally: some of your values look like numbers - if they are, then you should not surround them with single quotes (which are typically meant for strings). This makes the intent more obvious, and avoids the need for implicit conversion on database side.

Comment: thx you helped a lot :)